# Eb Deploy Deploying Old Running Version

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running into an odd issue in Elastic Beanstalk. When I deploy using `eb deploy`, I get this error:

```
During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.
```

I believe that the issue is coming because it is attempting to deploy a previously deployed running version. How can I specify the running version when deploying? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
eb deploy -l <version-label>
```

to specify which version do you want to [deploy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-deploy.html):

> Specify a label to use for the version that the EB CLI creates. If the label has already been used, the EB CLI **redeploys the previous version** with that label.

The following command will show the currently deployed version label:

```
eb status  | grep Version
```